Change the Shadow color of BottomAppBar and FloatingActionButton
I tried to change the shadow color of BottomAppBar and FloatingActionButton but failed. I want to adjust it like the photo below

Here is the code
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bab_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        app:elevation="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:fabCradleMargin="@dimen/_8sdp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="@dimen/_25sdp"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        android:outlineProvider="background"
        android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/color_button_main"
        android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/color_button_main"
        tools:targetApi="p">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bnv_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
            app:itemIconSize="@dimen/_20sdp"
            style="@style/MyBottomNavigationView"
            app:itemPaddingBottom="@dimen/_2sdp"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"/>

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/flb_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bab_main"
        app:backgroundTint="?color_button_main"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:maxImageSize="35dp"
        app:fabCustomSize="65dp"
        app:tint="?color_text_main_inverse"
        app:elevation="5dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:outlineSpotShadowColor="?color_button_main"
        android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="?color_button_main"
        android:contentDescription="@string/text_add_diary"
        tools:targetApi="p" />

I can't change the Shadow color of the BottomAppBar, it's still a gray color
As for FloatingActionButton, the Shadow will point downward, but I want it to spread around
Here is the resulting code


I think here is pretty much the same question as yours

(sorry, I've posted 2 the same comments)

As for the shadow part for the FloatingActionButton, I was able to handle it, but I still can't do it for the BottomAppBar
